# Optimizing the area of a square and circle

Tags: calculus

I am suppose to optimize the sum of the area of a square and a circle with a 12cm piece of wire to have the smallest area. To me this problem seems kind of obvious. A circle is a more efficient use of space so I know that it will have more area since it doesn't waste space on corners. This is a math thing I learned and I try and justify it by doing math stuff. I want the square as large as possible.

I know that the math on this is wrong when I do it but I can't make sense of it. I know that a square is more inefficient so don't I want to simply minimize the amount of the cirlce being used? Where does the logic come in that it should be somewhere in between?

The answer is 5.28cm for the circle but I don't understand the logic behind it, I thought I would want a small of a circle as possible. There must be some weird exponential growth of a circle past a certain point that I don't understand.

Comment: While it is true that for a given length of wire a circle will have more area than a square, a large square is more efficient that a small one.  If you make the circle zero size, you will have a square with area $9 cm^2$.  If you use $6 cm$ for each, the square has area $2.25 cm^2$ and the circle $2.865 cm^2$ for a total of $5.115 cm^2$.  This is not the minimum, but it shows that splitting the wire between the two shapes results in less area.

Comment: @Jordan: You have given a good intuitive argument for the fact that the **maximum** area is obtained by giving all the wire to the circle. However (beginning of the second line) the problem asks us to **minimize** the area.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I was just trying to do the opposite of the max.

Comment: You do say, correctly, that the circle will have *more* area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the amount of wire used on the square be $x$ so that the amount of wire used on the circle is $12-x$.  The sum of the areas in terms of $x$ is then

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{(12-x)^2}{4 \pi}$$

Find the $x$ that minimizes area by solving $f'(x)=0$:

$$\frac{x}{8} - \frac{12-x}{2 \pi}=0 \implies x=\frac{6/\pi}{(1/8)+(1/(2 \pi))} = \frac{48}{\pi +4}\approx 6.72119$$

Note that $f''(x) > 0$, so this is indeed a minimum.  Plug this value of $x$ into $f(x)$ to get this minimum area.

Comment: I lose you after f(x) I don't see what you did. Really though I was more interested in why my logic is wrong rather than how to find the answer. Should I just omit logic when working with math? That seems to be the regular answer, to not think about a problem but just use memorized formulas.

Comment: @Jordan: you seem pretty pessimistic.  This is the way that mathematics works.  Besides, I am not sure what exactly I was supposed to comment on.  You make a few vague statements about the inefficiency of squares and then out pops a number, 5.28 cm, without any context or clue as to where it comes from.  Meanwhile, let's examine my solution a little bit more.  The square has weight $1/16$, the circle has weight $1/(4 \pi)$, which is a bit bigger.  So there's your "efficiency."  Other than that, my solution reflects how such problems have been solved for centuries.

Comment: As for my $f(x)$, $x$ is the perimeter; the side of the square is $x/4$, the area is the side squared.

Comment: I am as confused as you are as to where that 5.28 comes from, it is  THE ANSWER from the book with no explanation as to why it exists. I am just trying to figure out how to do math without rote memorization of meaningless formulas. I guess that was a mistake.

Comment: @Jordan:  the 5.28 is the amount of wire for the circle, which is $12-x$

Comment: @RossMillikan: I can't believe I didn't see that .

Comment: I still don't follow the first line, where is the division coming from.

Comment: @Jordan: what division?  You mean $x^2/16$?  See above: $(x/4)^2 = x^2/16$.  For the circle, use the circumference $C = 2 \pi r$.

Comment: @Jordan: understanding the problem comes from understanding the function $f(x)$, which tells you how the total area changes as you you move wire between the circle and the square. Graph the function, and stare at it for a while. If the graph tells you things that are contrary to your intuition, then your intuition is wrong. Figure out why, so that your intuition will work better next time. The rest of the solution is just standard brain-dead stuff -- you find a minimum by setting a derivative equal to zero. Formulas for derivatives *are* just rote memorization (in calculus classes, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Ron Gordon already showed you how to do it mathematically, but I want to tell you why your intuition is wrong. You are correct about the circle being the most efficient at capturing area,  and your reasoning was a very good try; but you forgot one thing: the number of figures also matters. For example, if you cut a square in half, the two halves will add up to the original area, but your perimeter is larger. I hope this makes sense.